# Java function arguments converted to arg1, arg2, arg3 when the number of arguments is greater than 3

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, arguments

I am trying to build my project via maven and in the final Jar obtained I could see a strange behaviour. The functions having arguments greater than 3 gets their argument names changed to arg1, arg2, arg3 ...

Is this intended or is there any way to avoid this ?

Any help could be great

Comment: How are you viewing the argument names?

Comment: I am trying to use the generated jar in another project. Where in eclipse suggestion it shows the argument names as ( String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, Integer arg4)

Comment: Parameter names are normally not present in the bytecode. Two ways you might see the real parameter names: 1. Attach the project sources. 2. Compile with the `-paramters` option to javac, which saves the parameter names in class file. Are you doing either of those?

Comment: Great @dnault I haven't done both. It works after using -parameters thanks for the help.